# Facebook SDK Login Window - "Continue" button missed on Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

My application is works in landscape mode and I have one issue on small screen devices with facebook sdk - on login confirmation window there are must be button "Continue" but it's not there.

Screenshot:
[image]

This facebook window cannot be scrolled so login is impossible.
Device screen is 480 x 800.

Comment: does anyone faced with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I fixed by use portrait mode for Facebook Login

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: On small screen devices it might be OK

Comment: But if device have large screen, it will force login screen show in portrait mode anyway
is it possible to dynamically determine in which mode to show login screen?